# PHP version unsupported

Tags: php, linux, apache

Hello I am confuse I have two server one is running PHP 5.6.10 (cli) (buit: jun 11) 2015) , Zend engine  V2.6.0 and the other one is running PHP 5.5.38 (cli) (buit: jan 11 2019) Zend engine  V2.5.0. , the first one my Vulnerability scanner (Nessus enterprise) said that the version is fine but the second one the Vulnerability scanner (Nessus enterprise) said that is unsupported , could please explain me why does is happening , because I see the first server less version that the   second server. Also I check that both web server are running and responding to the scan.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide more details in your question if you want a correct answer. What do you mean by ***scanner*** or ***scan***? what is the name of the tool? Also it's clear that your first server use a higher version of PHP (5.6 > 5.5), probably your software only supports PHP v5.6 and upward but since you don't provide us anything, we can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what scanner you are using, but the PHP versions on both of your servers are no longer supported since 2017. It would be prudent to upgrade the PHP version on both of your servers to at least PHP 7.3

Using old versions is insecure and could lead to hacks and data breaches. You can see the current supported PHP versions here - https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: Thank you for you answer  , I have done some research and I realize that the problem might be the Zend Engine version, because in the server what the vulnerability dot no appear have a Zend version 2.0.6 higher  that the other one.